# iOS UIPickerview disappears in didSelectRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

iOS 8
Xcode 6.3
I have a picker view which has 2 components. I bring the picker view once user clicked on a textfield.
Once user selects a value in picker view it disappears!
Please see code below:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == 0) {
        ccYearTF.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] + 2015];
    }
    else {
        ccMonthTF.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] + 1];
    }
}
```

If I don't set value of the textfields it works normally and doesn't disappear, but if I set textfield's value then it disappears. Who can tell why is this happening?

Comment: Is the picker view the text field's `inputView`? Is the text field resigning first responder (that will hide the input view)?

Comment: picker view is not text field's inputView. I just bring up picker view animated when text field is tapped. And when select a value from picker I set that to text field.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the TextField delegate? What's happening when textField become first responder, and also when it calls: shouldChangeText.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are trying to do something like that, i had similar problem and only on ios 8. 
Check this question too [iOS8: What's going on with moving views during keyboard transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112319/ios8-whats-going-on-with-moving-views-during-keyboard-transitions)
Do not use storyboard

```
//Do not link with storyboard
@property UIPickerView *pickerview;
//in view didload
self.pickerview = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width+1,ccYearTF.frame.origin.y+60,self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
self.pickerview.dataSource = self;
self.pickerview.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.pickerview];
```

when you press ccYearTf textfiled

```
  -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
     if(textField == ccYearTf )
     { 
         [textField resignFirstResponder];
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
             [self.pickerview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _pickerview.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, _pickerview.frame.size.height)];
         }completion:nil];
      }
  }
```

now on 'pickerView didSelectRow' your pickerview wont disappear
hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. However, I've contacted Apple technical support a week ago and finally they replied.
Here is what they suggested:

> The issue of the UIPickerView disappearing when a selection has been made may be a bug. Please consider filing a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com, and attach your sample project. As a workaround, please create the picker view and the toolbar programmatically, and only as needed.

I haven't tried to add the picker manually yet, but I've submitted a bug report. I'll update here once fixed.